# Определить с какого из сайтов пришёл запрос

Tags: php, .htaccess, редирект

Есть два адреса сайта
site1.ru - основной сайт
site2.ru
Для второго сайта задана DNS адресация на первый сайт

Вопрос в том как определять пользователей пришедших со второго сайта на первом в .htaccess?

*Тут нужно впервые пришедшим пользователям со второго сайта один раз отобразить одну доп. страницу.*

Comment: в htaccess пишите куки или get параметры в зависимости от домена

Answer (score 1):

к примеру, можно просто перенаправить все обращения к доменному имени `site2.ru` на обращения к *допстранице* домена `site1.ru`. примерно так:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.ru [nocase]
rewriterule .* http://site1.ru/dopstranica [last,redirect=301]
```

Comment: Я так пробовал делать, но условие не отлавливает site2.ru.
При запросе site2.ru получаем ответ:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.site1.ru/

Comment: так и должно быть. только location должен быть `site1.ru/dopstranica`. если, конечно, не вмешиваются какие-нибудь ранее встречающиеся правила.

Comment: site2.ru/any_url -> site1.ru/any_url
а требуется на site1.ru отловить что запрос пришёл с site2.ru и перебрасывать всегда на
site1.ru/dopstranica

Comment: @CaSPeR, что в вашем понимании означает «запрос пришёл с site2.ru (на site1.ru)», учитывая, что это один и тот же сайт?

Comment: Пользователь в браузере переходит по ссылке site2.ru/any_url

Comment: @CaSPeR, вот его браузер и получит перенаправление на `site1.ru/dopstranica`, как и предложено в моём ответе. а дальше, при «хождении» по `site1.ru`, перенаправление выдаваться уже не будет. если вам требуется иное поведение, то внесите, пожалуйста, корректировки в вопрос, нажав [edit], или задайте новый вопрос с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу этой страницы.

Comment: @CaSPeR, если же вы наблюдаете переход (на `site1.ru`, а не на `site1.ru/dopstranica`), то, значит, у вас где-то ещё есть перенаправляющее правило. скорее всего, в конфигурации *http*-сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая переменная `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, в которую записывается имя сайта, с которой пришел запрос.

На сайте, на котором надо показывать дополнительную страницу, пишем в файле *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (site2.ru)
RewriteRule .* http://site1.ru/dopstranica.html [R=302,L]
```